# Line going from one instance to the other

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, object, instance, draw

lets say I have a library object (node1) which i have instantiated twice (mc1 & mc2) in two different random positions that may and probably change when the program runs. How can I create a line that will automatically go from one instance's position to the other?
Code example will be very nice.

ANY answer is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a sprite over or below the two movie clips, then use `Graphics.moveTo` / `Graphics.lineTo` to draw the line:

```
var g:Graphics = someSprite.graphics;
g.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
g.graphics.moveTo(mc1.x, mc1.y);
g.graphics.lineTo(mc2.x, mc2.y);
```

Comment: So it will line the two objects mc1 and mc2? is someSprite a keyword or just random text? too i need an addChild(); function or anything else for that?